# Bootstrap search from rails 4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I want to create a search from using the gem 'bootstrap_form' in my RoR application

this is how i proceed :

```
<%= bootstrap_form_tag(books_search_path, :method => "get", id: "search-form") do |f| %>
 <%= f.search_field :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search books" %>
 <%= f.submit "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

but i got this error in the first line:

> wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with this code:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_tag(url: books_search_path, method: "get", id: "search-form") do |f| %>
 <%= f.search_field :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search books" %>
 <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```